# code not executing due to huge time taken

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Inputs n,m
I wrote this code which will find smallest number such that
no. will be divisible by n
and sum of its digits = m
but its not executing, its taking too much time and not showing any output

I tried to run i from n+1 to INT_MAX but its not making any difference

```
#include <iostream>
#include<climits>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, m, a;
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i = n + 1; i < INT_MAX; i++)
    {
        a = 0;
        if (i % n == 0)
        {
            while (i > 0)
            {
                a += i % 10;
                i = i / 10;
            }
            if (a == m)
            {
                cout << a;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (a == m)
            break;
    }
}
```

I expect output to be some number but its showing nothing

Comment: What is the input you're using? What do you expect for the output? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: `i = i / 10;` looks bad as `i` is also used here `for (int i = n + 1; i < INT_MAX; i++)`

Comment: Why you have put second if condition (a == m) ??

Answer (score 0):

**** EDIT

in your loop i is being incremented by 1 in each loop and then divided by 10 , therefore it is never truly increasing and neither is a, so it never reaches a hit and is stuck in a loop approaching positive 0

Answer (score 0):

Don't use i in while loop as you are using i in for loop already. Using i in while loop decremented its value by i/10 time, every time while loop is executed. Instead use any other local variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<climits>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int n, m, a;
   cin >> n >> m;
   for (int i = n + 1; i < INT_MAX; i++)
   {
       a = 0;
       if (i % n == 0)
       {
           int temp = i;
           while (temp > 0)
           {
               a += temp % 10;
               temp = temp / 10;
           }
           if (a == m)
           {
               cout << a;
               break;
           }
       }
       if (a == m)
           break;
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another improvement: `for (int i = n; i < INT_MAX; i+=n)` eliminates the need for `if (i % n == 0)` There's no point testing any values between `n`s as they automatically fail. Ultimately though I'm pretty sure there's a way to hack the problem down to one equation.